# Get rid of horizontal scroll bar on mobile view

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I created this website to be responsive. The problem is that when horizontal screen size is 425 px or less, horizontal scrolling bar appears.

I spent hours and I can't find the cause of it.

[Here is the website deployed](https://francig.github.io/static/)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zVoS.png)

And the code

[CSS file](https://github.com/FranciG/static/blob/master/style.css)

[HTML](https://github.com/FranciG/static/blob/master/index.html)

[Github repo](https://github.com/FranciG/static)

Hope someone can give me a hand, thanks!

Comment: Hi, please include all the *relevant* code in the question.  *The question should be updated to include desired behaviour, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*  Have a read of [mcve] and provide the *minimal* code to reproduce it.  You may find that by going through the exercise of creating the minimal code you find your issue - that's why you go through that exercide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the site you posted, your problem is your footer

```
.reg {
  padding: 20px;
}

.barra .mail {
  width: 350px
}
```

it has fixed size of 350px + some padding from it's father reg.

Adjust that appropriately and you are done.

I'd suggest when you make a responsive design try to avoid from using fixed width\height